# Problem KCL in PSPICE simulation

Tags: current, kirchhoffs-laws, pspice

I have simulated the following circuit and have trouble with it.

[image: Schematic]

Why are the input and output currents are not equal?
Is this problem from me or with SPICE?

Comment: Using LTspice, with `BC857A` and `BC847A`, I get `241.8376nA` and `-241.85314nA`. The differences could be because of the way the solver tries to find the operating point (`.op`). It is the result of an iterative process (Newton-Raphson, or similar), which can yield differences even between two runs. However, in your case, that `pA` value does seem strange. Are you sure you get the correct reading? As in, make sure it's taken straight from the transistor's base, maybe try additional `.ic` settings?

Comment: I only have LTspice at hand and the B-version of the transistors. I  cannot reproduce the phenomenon. Please try the following: insert a resistor between the two bases and set its value to 0. You can also try to set it to a very low value other than 0.

Comment: Many simulators have a resistance or conductance automatically added from every node to ground since they can't handle truly floating nodes. (They don't conserve charge and need galvanic connections everywhere.) You might first check out that possibility. The base currents should match, as you imagine. Which is why I'm wondering about hidden node connections to ground. (I've read that PSpice _may_ require every node to have a DC path to node 0.)

Comment: @jonk I don't have PSpice, though I did hear the same thing about the need for conductances from "open" nodes, but would that apply here, too? I am thinking in terms of the expanded model, under the hood, it should have at least the `Rce`, `Rbe`, `Rcb` resistances, shouldn't it?

Comment: What's concerning me about the results you seem to be getting is that each BJT has three ports. The way things are wired there, the base currents should match very closely (within simulation errors.) Technically, charge must be conserved and it cannot accumulate in a node (or deplete from one.) So this leaves me wondering about the simulator stuffing in conductances to ground at every node. This would provide another path. I'm not saying it accounts for what you are seeing. I'm just wondering what else might be the answer here? Different beta and Is for the two BJTs can't explain it.